# JPA serialize enttiy

Tags: json, jpa, serialization, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have my data model that contains 3 tables: User, Profile, UserProfile.

```
public class User implements Serializable {

 private Integer id;
 ......

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = 
 FetchType.LAZY)
 @JsonManagedReference
 @JsonProperty("profiles")
 private List<UserProfile> userProfiles = new ArrayList<UserProfile>();

}

public class Profile implements Serializable {
 private Integer id;
 ......

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="profile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  fetch = 
 FetchType.LAZY)
 @JsonBackReference
 private List<UserProfile> userProfiles= new ArrayList<UserProfile>();

}

public class UserProfile implements Serializable {
 private Integer id;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "idUser")
 @JsonBackReference
 private User user;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "idProfile")
 @JsonManagedReference
 private Profile profile;
}
```

And here’s my json feed back:

{
    "id": 1,
    .......
    "profiles": [
        {
            "profile": {
                "id": 1,
                 .....
             },
             {
                 "id": 2,
                 .....
              }
         }
    ]
}

I have two questions:
Is it possible to remove the profile attribute and have:
{
    "id": 1,
    .......
    "profiles": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          .....
        },
        {
           ": 2,
           .....
        }
    ]
}

In a manytomany relationship with an intermediate table that contains a primary key (id), 2 foreign key that are the ids of the 2 tables that have the manytomany relationship, is that how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st question, to hide `profile` attribute, there are 2 options:
1. If you don't need it in any json output, you can add a `@JsonIgnore` annotation to it;
2. If you need it elsewhere but don't want it here, you can use `Projection`. Check  https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections and    https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-projections-excerpts for reference on how to use projections.

Comment: I wonder if this is achievable because when I want to make an update I couldn’t think because I wouldn’t have all my Id. When I am going to make an update on the user, it must also update information in the UserProfile table.

Comment: Help me please. It is very important

Answer (score 0):

Checked your code again. Your code has some problem.
You only need 2 entities: `User` and `Profile`. And just add `@ManyToMany` relationship to them.
Refer here for a complete sample on `ManyToMany` https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I need the UserProfile link entity because after I will add other fields in it

Comment: Help me. It is urgent